# Inner product and norm of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have recently started a undergraduate linear algebra course in which these definitions came up:

> Let $V$ be the vector space $C[a, b]$ of all continuous functions on $[a, b]$. Then the inner product and norm are defined as:
>
> \begin{align}
>     \langle f, g \rangle &= \int_a^b f(t) g(t) \,\mathrm{d}t
>     \\
>     \| f \| &= \sqrt{\langle f, f \rangle} = \sqrt{\int_a^b f^2(t) \,\mathrm{d}t}
>   \end{align}

**Concerns:**

What does it mean if $\int_a^b f^2(t) \,\mathrm{d}t < 0$?

It is also, strangely, possible to calculate the angle between functions (non-linear), is this considered the average angle in $[a, b]$ or what is it’s geometrical representation?

Comment: $\int_{a}^{b}f^2(t)dt$ is always positive for $a<b$.

Comment: I did not know that. But is not $C[1,0]$ the same vector space? Or is it a necessity that a<b when vector spaces are defined?

Comment: The standard interval notation $[a,b]$ means $a<b$.

Comment: @AdamYac : there are many inner products on $V$.  Whoever wrote that definition was sloppy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is important to note that the (inner-product) space you are working with is not the product of $[a,b]$ and the image of functions $f$. It is the infinite dimensional space of continuous functions defined on $[a,b]$. You should picture each $f$ in that space as an infinite vector.

Comment: Alright, I did not have that picture in mind but I do see your point. A question I should not ask but since we can deal with all kinds of C^0-functions; I know a vector have magnitude and direction but is it necessary a straight line?

Comment: Or should I imagine all kinds of elementary functions as infinite straight vectors? In that case the angle makes more sense..

Comment: Yes, linearity here comes the view that you treat each function as an infinite vector. The area of mathematics that studies this (among other things) is "functional analysis".